# split data with query

Tags: sql

i have data like this

```
TrNo | LAR | Model   | Transport

001    S001  P-123     30000
001    S001  Service   15000
002    S002  P-345     30000
003    S003  P-567     30000
003    S003  Service   15000
```

and i want this table become

```
TrNo   | LAR  | Model | Transport Model | Transport Service

001      S001   P-123   30000             15000
002      S002   P-345   30000               -
003      S003   P-567   30000             15000
```

Please help me...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using..?

Comment: Either a GROUP BY with case expressions, or a self full outer join.

Comment: not clear what you are looking for. are you looking for how rename column names?

Comment: You want a pivot table. Check if your DBMS implements PIVOT operator, otherwise follow the path as @jarlh said.

Answer (score 0):

Idea:
Select all records with Model <> Service - now you have all your models.
Then do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to the same table again with Model = Service.

should work like:

```
           SELECT COALESCE(Model.TrNo,Service.TrNo)     AS TrNo
                 ,COALESCE(Model.LAR,Service.LAR)       AS LAR
                 ,COALESCE(Model.Model,Service.Model)   AS Model
                 ,COALESCE(Model.Transport,0)           AS TransportModel
                 ,COALESCE(Service.Transport,0)         AS TransportService
             FROM yourtable Model
  FULL OUTER JOIN yourtable Service
               ON Service.TrNo   = Model.TrNo
              AND Service.Model  = 'Service'
            WHERE Model.Model   <> 'Service'
```

Comment: I'd do a FULL OUTER JOIN to also include rows with only service.

Comment: @jarlh: really depends on the data, but you're right. its a "safer" way. i updated the answer.

Comment: i'm used language visual basic 6 and i used that's script for query